# How to put socket file descriptor in a buffer and continue accepting incoming connections?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to design a multithreaded web server in C using Pthreads and i am having a problem in accepting more incoming connections without serving them.

I want to put the file descriptor of each recieved connection in a buffer to be pocessed by a thread, Im using default accept(2) for accepting clients connections.

should i be using select ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you looking for easy coding or high performance? Do you want to do it yourself or use a library? If you care about performance, do you need high throughput or high number of connections or both?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz its better to use a library and easy coding, because its just a part of the design, i'll only be testing the number of connection.

Comment: Then look at Boost::asio or libevent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Has to be libevent since the OP is coding in C.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, do you mean you want to put the accepted socket in a queue, to be processed by a thread at a later time?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes exactly, but i want to process each incomming connection with a thread instantly, so the process may serve multiple clients insted of waiting for a client to finish. Thank you for the code that you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way of doing multi-threaded servers is to create a new thread right after you accept a new connection, and pass the new socket to that thread. Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* ... */
    int client_socket = accept(server_socket);

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, my_connection_handler, (void *) client_socket);
    /* ... */
}

void *my_connection_handler(void *argp)
{
    int socket = (int) argp;

    write(socket, "Hello!\r\n", 8);

    close(socket);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Just be warned that while this is the simplest way and the way you should usually learn first, the performance is terrible. You have to create a new thread and wait for it to get the CPU before you can start servicing a new connection. And worse, to do a little bit of work on each of 100 connections requires 100 context switches. Also, if the threads wind up accessing common data structures, you get bad behavior from the synchronization on those data structures.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So if  i used a fixed size pool of worker threads, and synchronize the shared memory using mutex or semaphores, it will start receving connectoin when ever one is passed to a worker thread ?

Comment: @CodeRed: That's a common way to do it. It's still not great for many of the reasons I explained above -- it requires lots and lots of context switches and the large number of thread (one per client) makes synchronization inefficient. (For example, a bunch of data comes in, a bit for each of 80 clients, so all 80 threads wake only to wind up blocking on the same synchronization object which each of the 80 threads get in turn. You wind up with hundreds of context switches for no reason.)

Answer (score 0):

I read this article these days (i didn't try, but looks good):
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/network-programming-enet
or libevent too.

If you want code by your own hands, look at  (performance ideas):
http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html